# Django - wagtail Inline panel CSS edits

Tags: python, django

I am using wagtail on django and creating a page where I will create questions and allow students to answer it by typing in the input box. I am using **inline** field where the wagtail gives me the option to choose various input option like(singleline, multiline, radio button etc). For my questions, I am choosing a singleline option. The problem I am facing is with the text box, the text box is too small, is there a way to increase the size(width) of the text box.

*model.py*

```
class QuestionPage(AbstractForm):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)
    points_for_this_activity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Create your question"),
        FieldPanel('points_for_this_activity', classname="title"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
    ]
```

*question.html*

```
<div class ="container">
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

        {% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_active or request.is_preview %}
            {% if form %}
                <div>{{ page.intro|richtext }}</div>
                <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input class="btn-md btn-primary"  type="submit">
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <div>You have already answered this. Go to the next question.</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <div>To fill in the form, you should log in.</div>
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```